# apache is downloading page instead of displaying it

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt

Everything was working fine. I enables https and now the index page is asking me to save it. It is blank.

I used cetbot, everything went well. Then when I go to my home page is prompts me to save it.

Any ideas?

I have double checked the config files the seem to be ok. I checked that port 443 is visable it is, I disabled the firewall that did not help.